# ELF label address

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, elf, relocation

I have the following code in .s file:

```
pushq $afterjmp
    nop
afterjmp:
    movl %eax, %edx
```

Its object file has the following:

```
20: 68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
25: 90                      nop
0000000000000026 <afterjmp>:
26: 89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
```

After linking, it becomes:

```
400572: 68 78 05 40 00          pushq  $0x400578
400577: 90                      nop
400578: 89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
```

How does the argument `0x0` to `pushq` at byte `20` of the object file gets converted to `0x400578` in the final executable?

Which section of the object file contains this information?

Comment: The object file (and the sections it contains) doesn't know where it will be placed in the final executable. That is driven by the linker (and internal linker scripts by default). If you use `objdump -Dr filename.o` you can see where the relocations will be. 00 00 00 00 is a placeholder that will end up being filled in by the linker (in this case)

Comment: @MichaelPetch, Thanks, it helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You answered your own question: `After linking...`.

Here is a good article:

[Linkers and Loaders](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6463)

In particular, note the section about "symbol relocation":

> Relocation. Compilers and assemblers generate the object code for each
>   input module with a starting address of zero. Relocation is the
>   process of assigning load addresses to different parts of the program
>   by merging all sections of the same type into one section. The code
>   and data section also are adjusted so they point to the correct
>   runtime addresses.

There's no way to know the program address of "afterjmp" when a single object file is assembled.  It's only when all the object files are assembled into an executable image can the addresses (relative to offset "0") be computed.  That's one of the jobs of the linker: to keep track of "symbol references" (like "afterjmp"), and compute the machine address ("symbol relocation").

Comment: FWIW, he asked where this can be found in the object file. Well, the object file does have a list of addresses that must be relocated, I guess.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yeah, indeed.